# TinyMCE Toolbar location

Tags: javascript, tinymce, toolbar

How can the Toolbar be displayed on a defined Place (div with specific id)?

I tried theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "external" and setting the position of the "mceExternalToolbar" (like suggested here: [TinyMCE - external toolbar position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723410/tinymce-external-toolbar-position)) but don't really like this solution since it uses fixed positioning....
Is there a option how to where to place the div.

The docu says for theme_advanced_toolbar_location:

> .. adds the toolbar to a DIV element and sets the class of this DIV to
>   "mceExternalToolbar". ...
>   but not if you can change the div. is there maybe a possibilty to change this code?

BR,
Stefan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been an issue for me a few months ago. All you need to do is to move the external toolbar to the place you want it to be. I wrote a function in one of my plugins.
On my page i have created a div with class "externalToolbarWrapper" in which i insert the toolbar. Here is that function. You might need to tweak it a bit, but think it will be of help to you.

```
    showExternalToolbar: function(){

        if (this.editor.getParam('theme_advanced_toolbar_location') != 'external') return;

        if (!document.getElementById('externalToolbarWrapper')) $(document.body).prepend('<div id="externalToolbarWrapper"></div>');

        var $toolbar = $('#'+this.editor.id + '_external');

        // inserts the external toolbar in the external wrapper
        $('#externalToolbarWrapper').append('<div id="replacementDiv"></div>');

        $('#replacementDiv').replaceWith($toolbar.show());
        $toolbar.css('top','0px');
        $toolbar.css('display','block');

        $('#' + this.editor.id + '_external_close').remove();
        $('#' + this.editor.id +'_toolbargroup').css('width', innerWidth || 800); // innerwidth is an integer value
    },
```

**Update:**

You should call it onInit (use the [setup configuration parameter](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3asetup) here)

```
   setup : function(ed) {
      ed.onInit.add(function(ed) {
          // place your code here
      });
   },
```

Comment: hi thanks, but where do I have to put this code? I added it to the init parameters but this does nothing.......

Comment: nonono, you will eigther put this function into an own plugin or include it using the setup configuration parameter into your tinymce inti function

Comment: ok^, well I'm new to tinymce. Is there a discription for tinymce plugin development?

Comment: that one is ok, the official guide to create a plugin can be found here: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Creating_a_plugin . the setup parameter might be sufficient for you if you do not want to create an onw plugin: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:setup

Comment: thanks, well I have to get to know tinymce better anyway, niceEdit has way to less functionality and isn't further developed... :/

Comment: it takes some time to get into it, but for the most part it is worth it

Comment: @Thariama, I tried this out but it gives the following error:  this.editor is undefined.
This is how I'm doing it:  
  
tinyMCE.init({  
theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "external",  

/*other config stuff*/
  
setup : function(editor) {    

editor.onInit.add(function(editor) {    

var $toolbar = $('#'+this.editor.id + '_external');    

/* rest of the code */

});  
},  
});  
  


  
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @user961627: you may use tinymce.activeEditor instead (guess this.editor is undefined in your case)

Comment: @user961627: yes, that's a third option :)