# put tinymce toolbar on external div

Tags: jquery, html, css, tinymce, html-editor

How can I put tinymce toolbar on external div?
I try this successfull:

[TinyMCE Toolbar location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819966/tinymce-toolbar-location)

It put toolbar on external but it doesn't load css theme for displaying toolbar, because css are load in iframe, so toolbar isn't shown.

Answer (score 2):

This has been an issue for me a few months ago. All you need to do is to move the external toolbar to the place you want it to be. I wrote a function in one of my plugins.
On my page i have created a div with class "externalToolbarWrapper" in which i insert the toolbar. Here is that function. You might need to tweak it a bit, but think it will be of help to you.

```
    showExternalToolbar: function(){

        if (this.editor.getParam('theme_advanced_toolbar_location') != 'external') return;

        if (!document.getElementById('externalToolbarWrapper')) $(document.body).prepend('<div id="externalToolbarWrapper"></div>');

        var $toolbar = $('#'+this.editor.id + '_external');

        // inserts the external toolbar in the external wrapper
        $('#externalToolbarWrapper').append('<div id="replacementDiv"></div>');

        $('#replacementDiv').replaceWith($toolbar.show());
        $toolbar.css('top','0px');
        $toolbar.css('display','block');

        $('#' + this.editor.id + '_external_close').remove();
        $('#' + this.editor.id +'_toolbargroup').css('width', innerWidth || 800); // innerwidth is an integer value
    },
```

You should call the above code onInit if you don't want to place it inside an own plugin (use the [setup configuration parameter](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3asetup) here)

```
   setup : function(ed) {
      ed.onInit.add(function(ed) {
          // place your code here
      });
   },
```

Comment: Ok I already create a plugin and put toolbar external. My problem is that toolbar isn't displayed because all css of toolbar are loaded in iframe and not in main document. How can I load necessary css file in main document for styling toolbar?

Comment: have alook at the editor_css setting - css for tinymce toolbar elements should be placed there

Answer (score 0):

Guys if U wanna try this, its even easier and short

```
setup:function(ed){
    ed.onInit.add(function(ed, evt){
        $toolbar = $('#'+ed.id+'_external');
        $toolbar.hide().appendTo('yourExternalDiv');
    });
}
```

"Munsif Mulla"